# Can vc-dir be set to show up-to-date files?

Tags: emacs

is it possible to get the up-to-date files back in a `*vc-dir*` buffer?  up to now I've been using `psvn.el` (and before that `cvs-examine`), both have a command that allow me to see the full content/status of the tree.

if there is something like this in `*vc-dir*`, I don't manage to find it.

if there isn't, how do you guys and girls use it?

---

so it looks like the functionality is not there yet, and now I think that this question was correctly moved from programmers to stackoverflow: it's not about the tool itself, but how to expand it.

I had a look at the sources and I think that I need a function to recurse a subdir only including those files that are known to be under version control.  if this function existed and was called `vc-dir-find-versioned-child-files`, then the solution would be close to this:

```
     (define-key map [follow-link] 'mouse-face)
     (define-key map "x" 'vc-dir-hide-up-to-date)
+    (define-key map "X" 'vc-dir-show-child-files)
     (define-key map "S" 'vc-dir-search) ;; FIXME: Maybe use A like dired?
     (define-key map "Q" 'vc-dir-query-replace-regexp)
```

and

```
 (ewoc-set-hf vc-ewoc (vc-dir-headers backend def-dir) ""))))

+(defun vc-dir-show-child-files ()
+  "expand the directory under the cursor"
+  (interactive)
+  (let ((files (vc-dir-find-versioned-child-files (vc-dir-current-file)))
+        fileentries)
+    (when files
+      (dolist (crt files)
+        (push (list (file-relative-name crt) (vc-state crt))
+              fileentries))
+      (vc-dir-update fileentries (current-buffer)))))

 (defun vc-dir-show-fileentry (file)
```

close, but not exactly, as the status is not correctly computed, it now gives a `nil`.

what I still miss in `vc-dir` is information like who did the last commit and the number of the revision for each entry (preferably local and remote).  but I'm not good enough to interact with LISP.

---

if `vc-dir` does not do what I need, what about `ecb`?

Comment: I had put this question on programmers.stackexchange because it's not strictly a programming question, it's just about a tool I use.  ...  emacs questions, one never knows where they belong to!

Comment: there's a bug report for this: http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=3641

Answer (score 2):

It appears that vc-dir is hard coded to hide up-to-date files. There is a function `vc-dir-hide-up-to-date` that does the opposite of what you want, and since vc-dir uses ewoc, it shouldn't be too hard to mirror it. I can take a stab at it later if no one has any better ideas.

Comment: I gave a quick look at it.  `vc-dir-hide-up-to-date` scans the files already in the buffer, it doesn't look at the files in the directory. anyhow, the functionality is not there, is it?  but the building blocks are, we just need to put things together...  I'll have a look at it today maybe.

Comment: had a further look at it, I still miss some function for gathering all versioned child files, but I also miss more functionality from `psvn.el`, so for the time being I think I will stick with that.